# Memory functionality in Apache spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have few questions about Memory  which is used in Apache Spark.

1) I/O operations are very slow if we read from hard drive, that's why if we put data in memory then its accessible very fast.

In this point my question is, Firstly everything is in hardisk, when spark starts then the data comes in memory to be operated from hardisk and when its done goes back to hardisk. So First and Last point always to hardisk then how its saving time for complete cycle in Spark ? Correct me if am wrong.

2) Is RDD a data set present in Memory ? In laymen terms.!!

Comment: Because first computation happen in the JVM which is allocated on the RAM as Java objects. Secondly, there is also what they call memory persistence. So you can ask Spark to save those data in the RAM so he doesn't need to compute them again. Which is much slower if it were to be saved on disk

Comment: Anyhow, your question is off-topic. I'm voting to close it for being broad. I advice you in all cases to follow the https://www.coursera.org/learn/scala-spark-big-data/ course, you'll understand spark basics in Laymen's terms from the first week.